# Python file not running in Packet Tracer

Tags: python, networking

I am supposed to submit a solution to a problem via a pkt file, the solution being coded in python. While my solution runs elsewhere perfectly (Vscode, onlinegdb) it won't run on the cisco packet tracer app. I haven't used Packet Tracer prior to this, and this submission is necessary if I want to gain a certain certification from my college.

Can anyone please guide what I should do?

```
import ipaddress #imported to use ipaddress values
def in_range(n): 
    if n >= 0 and n<=255:
       return True
    return False

def has_leading_zero(n): # function to check if every split has leading zero or not.
if len(n)>1:
    if n[0] == "0":
        return True
return False

def isValid(s):    #function to check if ipv4 address is valid or not

s = s.split(".")
if len(s) != 4: #if number of splitting element is not 4, it is not a valid ip address
    return 0
for n in s:
    
    if has_leading_zero(n):
        return 0
    if len(n) == 0:
        return 0
    try: #if int(n) is not an integer it raises an error
        n = int(n)

        if not in_range(n):
            return 0
    except:
        return 0
return 1


def hexadecimal(ip):     #function for hexadecimal conversion
parts=ip.split('.')
hexNumber= format(int(parts[0]), '02X') \
    + format(int(parts[1]), '02X') \
    + format(int(parts[2]), '02X') \
    +format(int(parts[3]), '02X')
return hexNumber 
    
def binary(ip):         #function for binary conversion
parts=ip.split('.')
binaryNumber= format(int(parts[0]), '08b') \
    + format(int(parts[1]), '08b') \
    + format(int(parts[2]), '08b') \
    +format(int(parts[3]), '08b')
return binaryNumber

def octal(ip):          #function for octal conversion
parts=ip.split('.')
octalNumber= format(int(parts[0]), '03o') \
    + format(int(parts[1]), '03o') \
    + format(int(parts[2]), '03o') \
    +format(int(parts[3]), '03o')
return octalNumber

def decimal(ip):        #function for decimal conversion
parts=ip.split('.')
decimalNumber= format(int(parts[0]), '03d') \
    + format(int(parts[1]), '03d') \
    + format(int(parts[2]), '03d') \
    +format(int(parts[3]), '03d')
return decimalNumber

def conversions(ip):    #function to do all conversions together
a=decimal(ip)
b=binary(ip)
c=octal(ip)
d=hexadecimal(ip)
return a, b, c, d


if __name__=="__main__":
print("Input 10 ipv4 addresses")
list=[]
finalLine=[]  
n=10
for i in range(0, n):
    ip=input()
    if ((isValid(ip))==True):
        list.append(ip)
    elif ((isValid(ip))==False):
        ip=format(ipaddress.ip_address(int(ip)))
        list.append(ip)
    
    
textfile = open("conversion.txt", "w")

for element in list:
    textfile.write(element+ "\n")
textfile.close()
    
with open('conversion.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


for line in lines:
    linePart=line.split("\n")
    finalLine.append(linePart[0])
f.close()

print(f"The first IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[0])} \n")
print(f"The second IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[1])} \n")
print(f"The third IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[2])} \n")
print(f"The fourth IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[3])} \n")
print(f"The fifth IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[4])} \n")
print(f"The sixth IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[5])} \n")
print(f"The seventh IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[6])} \n")
print(f"The eighth IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[7])} \n")
print(f"The ninth IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[8])} \n")
print(f"The tenth IP address in Decimal, Binary, Octal and hexadecimal format is {conversions(finalLine[9])} \n")
```

Comment: Packet Tracer is a simple simulation tool to help someone pass the CCNA exam. It does not have advanced features, and it is _not_ IOS, it is merely a simulation. Unless it directly impacts on passing the CCNA exam, Packet Tracer is the wrong tool for the job. As far as I know, Python programming has nothing to do with the CCNA.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware programming on Packet tracer is only supported on IoT devices like the Microcontrollers(MCUs) or LEDs etc.

This might help: https://www.packettracernetwork.com/internet-of-things/pt7-iot-devices-configuration.html